# What is the measure of $h(X)$ if $X$ has measure $\mu$?

Tags: measure-theory

What is the measure of $h(X)$ if $X$ has measure $\mu$? $h$ is some function?

My thinking is that we have $(h(X))(P)(A) = P(h(X) \in A) = P( (X^{-1} \circ h^{-1})(A)$ but then I am stuck. What happens now?

Comment: $X$ is a set or a random variable or what?

Answer (score 0):

Notations differ, but you want a formula for $P(h(X)\in A)$ assuming you know how to calculate $P(B)$ for measurable sets $B$, or a means to calculate $Ef(h(X))$ for continuous bounded functions $f$, assuming you know how to calculate $Eg(X)$ for continuous bounded functions $g$.

In the first case, $P(h(X)\in A) = P(\{\omega: h(X(\omega)\in A\}) = \mu(B)$ where $B=\{\omega: h(X(\omega)\in A\}$ is just another measurable set, whose probability you know how to evaluate.

In the second case, let $g(x) = f(h(x))$, and then $Eg(X)=Ef(h(X))$.